Is the notion of continuity of inner product meaningful?
Suppose $V$ is a normed space. Then an inner product is a function from $V \times V$ to the scalar field. Then we need to define a metric on the space $V \times V$ in order to discuss the continuity of inner products.
This is important since we cannot make sure that each individual component sequence converges respectively when we fix a convergent sequence in $V \times V$. But the convergence of each component is used in every proof I have seen. Example:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inner_Product_is_Continuous
My question is: Why is everyone talking about the continuity of inner product without mentioning explicitly the metric on $V \times V$?

Is your vector space finite dimensional? Do you know what a topological vector space is?

The linked proof does not claim that the inner product is jointly continuous on the product space. It indeed only makes the weaker claim that if you have two convergent sequences in the inner product space then when you take the inner product pointwise along the sequence you get a convergent sequence in the field.

(The page probably shouldn’t be called ‘inner product is continuous’)

@SBK which would be the definition of sequential continuity
Edit: Ok, this is not necessarily true if the topology on $V\times V$ is not the product topology.

For any norm $|\cdot |$ you have an induced metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. So this metric is tacitly used.

In topology, given a topological space $X$, we conventionally equip $X \times X$ with the product topology. This may or may not mean something to you, but it applies to metric spaces too. If $(X, d)$ is a metric space, we can define a metric $d'$ on $X \times X$ by$$d'((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2))=d(x_1, y_1) + d(x_2, y_2),$$and generate the product topology. The same topology is also generated by, say$$d'((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2))=\max{d(x_1, y_1), d(x_2, y_2)},$$or a myriad of other options. All generate the same topology, and produce the same notion of continuity.

@MoisheKohan maybe infinite dimension. Do you mean that the notion of continuity of inner product is also defined when viewing V as a topological vector space? I see, by doing this we can indeed show inner product to be continuous without notion of distance.

You just need topology to define continuity.


Suppose $V$ is a normed space.

No, your example assumes an inner product space and considers the norm induced by the inner product. The norm defines a metric which in turn defines a topology.

Then we need to define a metric on the space $V\times V$
in order to discuss the continuity of inner products.

As remarked by Moishe Kohan in the comments, you just need a topology to define continuity.

Why is everyone talking about the continuity of inner product without mentioning explicitly the metric on $V\times V$?

Because it is considered obvious that the topology in consideration is the product topology. In fact the result in your example can easily be used to deduce that the inner product is continuous w.r.t. the product topology.
Since the product topology is a rather small topology (namely the smallest topology such that all projections are continuous), it is worth noting that this implies that the inner product is continuous w.r.t. all topologies that contain the product topology.
